# how to retrieve array from session.subscribe()

Tags: javascript, neo4j

I am retrieving data from a Neo4J db with this code:

```
function findSystems() {
    var myarray = [];
    session
        .run('MATCH (i:something) WHERE i.aproperty = {nameParam} return i.name as aname LIMIT 100', {nameParam: 'TX'})
        .subscribe({
            onNext: function (record) {
                // add a single record
                myarray(record.get('aname');
            },
            onCompleted: function () {
                console.log(myarray);
                session.close();
            },
            onError: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                session.close();
            }
        });
}
```

Now it prints fine the myarray array to console onCompleted(), but I don't understand how to return the array out of this function so to use it in other part of my code... How to properly return myarray?

THe concrete case is I have a function giveMeData() that calls findSystems() and I need that findSystems() returns the array to the first function giveMeData()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to handle query responses with the [Bolt Javascript diver](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver):

- asynchronously (via `subscribe`)
- synchronously (via `then` and `catch`)

Since you want to get the result synchronously, you should be using `then` and `catch`.

[EDITED]

For example, this version of your function will return a promise, and the `doIt` function attaches a `then` call to that promise in order to know when to use the `myarray` value.

```
function findSystems() {
  var myarray = [];
  return session
    .run('MATCH (i:something) WHERE i.aproperty = {nameParam} return i.name as aname LIMIT 100', {nameParam: 'TX'})
    .then(function (result) {
      result.records.forEach(function (record) {
        myarray.push(record.get('aname'));
      });
      console.log(myarray);
      session.close();
      return myarray;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return null; // Return null if there is an error
    });
}

function doIt() {
  findSystems()
    .then(function(arr) {
      // Put your code here to use the value of arr.
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you for pulling me out of the JS madness... still you can test your function, if you put console.log(myarray); before the return statement, you will see that the array is empty

Comment: Does your Cypher query actually return any results?

Comment: sure thing, and the console.log(myarray) within the .then(){} writes all the values in the console

Comment: OK. Fixed my logic errors (I think, since I have not tested anything).

Answer (score 0):

**Simply you can't return value from the observable ,**

> so one way to solve is to set callback function / function in which
>   you need that result value, pass that function as parameter to the
>   findSystems function, that function will call your callback function
>   when the value is available.
>
> second way is to set event emitter , fire an event when the value is
>   available

You can use callback method as I suggested as first option :

```
function findSystems(callback) {
    var myarray = [];
    session
        .run('MATCH (i:something) WHERE i.aproperty = {nameParam} return i.name as aname LIMIT 100', {nameParam: 'TX'})
        .subscribe({
            onNext: function (record) {
                // add a single record
                myarray(record.get('aname');
            },
            onCompleted: function () {
                console.log(myarray);
                callback(myarray);
                session.close();
            },
            onError: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                session.close();
            }
        });
}

function callback(myarray)
{
    console.log(myarray);
}

findSystems(callback);
```

Comment: I don't get it... I want to return myarray out of this function

Comment: yes you will get it , in callback function will be called when your event will be finished

Comment: no I don't get it = I don't understand... I have a function that calls findSystems() and I want that findSystems() returns an array... is this any clearer?

Comment: you cant do that , because its observer , you can return only promise or observer from that function , you have to call the callback function or have to define varible gloablly and set it on complete , then you have to emit an event to notify that value is availble , getting my point ?

Comment: ok I think I am getting the logic here, thanks... do you have any example to update your answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: This is perfect example for explaining it , please accept the answer I am adding description for this situation

Comment: this is what I have with your solution:  TypeError: callback is not a function. (In 'callback(myarray)', 'callback' is undefined)

Comment: you have to pass callback function from findSystems as I have updated my answer , please check again.

Comment: I checked, but all I have with this cumbersome approach is at best an updated global variable, which I can define in the first place without callbacks... still don't understand how another function gets aware of the new value, which was my point in eventually accepting your answer...

Comment: because we are passing the latest value in callback function as parameter onCompleter event , please see that.